# In IntelliJ Idea why every folder "core" has special icon?

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea

Just out of curiosity, why in my IntelliJ Idea every folder named "core" has an unusual icon? I am using the Linux version of Idea. My OS is Ubuntu with Unity desktop environment.

[image: Navigation bar]

[image: Project tool window]

This feature seems interesting, is it configurable?

Comment: Do you use any custom theme plug-ins?

Comment: No, I don't. And it happens on every Ubuntu environment.

Comment: On the other hand, it can be that some of my old settings have this effect, because every time I install Idea on a new environment I always import my settings file. I didn't try it on a default version.